# MongoDB: How to set another field (different from _id) as ID of mongo document?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

For example, what if I would like to have Username as unique ID of my mongo document instead of having default "_id"?

I'd like to achieve this using mongo.exe console.

Comment: If usernames could ever change, and they're used in other documents, I'd recommend you do not make them the primary key (`_id`) as you'll need to update all locations that point to the new username (and you'll have a timing issue as there aren't transactions in MongoDB).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

MongoDB requires the _id property as the unique primary key that it automatically indexes.

You have two options:

1. Use the _id property and set it with the username.
2. Create a username property, then add an index on that new property. You will still have the _id, but can query using the username.

Comment: I know, that it is possible to have such record like {username: "John", age: 12}. I mean, without _id. How to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to remove the _id ?

Comment: When you define the username index you can require that it's unique, if that's your concern.  _id is small and helpful.  Just leave it alone and ignore it until you understand mongodb much better.

Comment: you can exlude `_id` from your queries results using the projection `{_id: false}` also

Answer (score 1):

`_id` is important in replication. You can create a collection without an `_id` index, but you **will never be able to replicate the database**. Replication requires the  `_id` index on every collection.

Answer (score 0):

> I know, that it is possible to have such record like {username: "John", age: 12}. I mean, without _id. How to do this?

I am unsure how @Serges answer was not clear enough however, to re-iterate, there is no way. Technically you can still take out the _id in a capped collection in some versions of MongoDB however, other than that you cannot.

Also I am concerned by your use of username, it might not be the best thing for activities such as sharding and could create "hotspots" of high acitivty on clusters etc, it is all theoretical since I am not in your position with your data, however, it is best to consider this stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but I just want to know, how is it possible. Let me provide some more details. I am using .NET driver and I can code like this: 

        class User
    {
        [BsonId]
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

When I put object of such class into mongodb, I am getting object without _id, and I am curious to know, how does driver interpret this object. How do the operation looks like?

Comment: @AndreiMikhalevich Wait, "When I put object of such class into mongodb, I am getting object without _id, " what do you mean? Are you saying you are saving an object with _id and it has no _id in the database? That's supposed to be impossible

Comment: @AndreiMikhalevich: If you insert an object without an `_id`, the C# driver will generate one for you.  The `_id` is a required primary key for a MongoDB document; you can choose to use your own identifiers or use the default [ObjectID](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/).

Comment: @Sammaye: The choice of `_id` is independent of your [choice of shard key](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-internals/#choosing-a-shard-key), which can include one or more fields.  The `_id` field is indeed immutable (cannot be changed once set), but username may be fine if an application doesn't allow users to change their name. If you need to change the `_id`, you can also copy + reinsert the document with a new `_id` (but have the extra work of updating any references to the original `_id`).

Comment: @Stennie I was concerned with the advice to put username as the _id of the document, since most shard on _id or something similar it was merely a concern I voiced